# Weird navigation behaviour between navigators in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having some trouble trying to navigate between Navigators in react-navigation

Here is my Navigator setup

```
// Root Navigator

const RootNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  Charities: {
    screen: CharitiesNavigator
  },
  Events: {
    screen: EventsNavigator
  },
  MapView: {
    screen: MapView
  }
}, {
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  backBehaviour: 'none',
  contentComponent: ({navigation})=> <Drawer navigation={navigation} />
})

// Charities

const CharitiesNavigator = StackNavigator({
  ChairtiesHome: {
    screen: Charities
  },
  CharityDetail: {
    screen: CharityDetail
  }
}, {
  headerMode: 'screen',
  backBehaviour: 'none',
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F7F9FA'
  }
})

// Events

const EventsNavigator = StackNavigator({
  EventsHome: {
    screen: Events
  },
  EventDetail: {
    screen: EventDetail
  }
}, {
  headerMode: 'screen',
  backBehaviour: 'none',
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F7F9FA'
  }
})
```

If a user is in the EventDetail screen, they can click a link which will take them to the CharityDetail screen for a given charity. However, if the user then wants to go back, the expected behaviour would be to go back to the EventsDetail screen we came from, but if you use either the hardware button on android or `goBack(x)` (I have tried null and passing a key) you end up in the Charities Home screen instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default operation of going back in a stack navigator, is popping a screen from the stack. When you navigate to the `CharityDetail` screen, you're really switching to the other navigator and then adding a screen to the stack.

I think you need to rethink the structure of your navigation tree, according to the behavior you want to achieve. While unifying the stack navigators would achieve the immediate behavior you're after, it might mess up the drawer. Then again, you can use the drawer to reset the stack navigator to whatever state you really want.

Comment: Thanks @kraylog I had a play around with ideas you had laid out and feel like the Navigation structure makes a lot more sense now as well as `react-navigation` itself!